# print ASCII characters in format of MySQL CHAR() function - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a problem with output from this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Write some text: "
text = gets.chomp

text.each_byte do |asc|
    print asc
end
puts
```

For example, I write text: **abc** and output is: **979899** in standard ASCII, but I'd like
to print it in format - ***CHAR(97, 98, 99)***

I tried it via functions split or squeeze, but for example split(',') is not, what I am looking for,
so if anyone can give me a hint how to do it, I'd be grateful.

Comment: It's generally better to read data from the command-line through `ARGV` or just use `STDIN` without prompting than to have some 1980s style "ENTER COMMAND" type prompt.

Comment: Using `STDIN` without prompting means you can do things like `echo 'test' | my_script | mysql ...` and use it as part of a process without having to strip off the "Write some text:" text. Using command-line arguments is even easier.

Comment: It's thing of opinions, but you're right. To me are ARGV scripts more comfortable too. This was just a simple script for try this "to CHAR" converting thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
puts "CHAR(#{text.each_byte.to_a.join(', ')})"
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly too. There aren't just spaces between numbers, but it's really isn't important. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Yeez: There are spaces between the numbers now. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Convert bytes to string:

```
'abc'.each_byte.map(&:to_s)
# => ["97", "98", "99"]
```

Join them with `,`:

```
'abc'.each_byte.map(&:to_s).join(', ')
# => "97, 98, 99"
```

Finally using string interpolation:

```
"CHAR(#{'abc'.each_byte.map(&:to_s).join(', ')})"
# => "CHAR(97, 98, 99)"
```

**UPDATE**

You can replace `map(&:to_s)` with `to_a` because `String#join` will conver items to strings.

Comment: @tadman, You're right. I didn't need to convert items to string. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The `&:to_s` part is equivalent to `{ |c| c.to_s }` for those that might not be familiar with that notation.